# 404 Not Found error after commit changes on PHP application Openshift

Tags: php, git, openshift

I'm having problems with my PHP applications, I have created and deleted several of them because everytime I commit changes my application crushes and it shows the "404 Not Found" error.

I'm sure there are no coding errors for two reasons:
1. The same code was working days ago, it was after wednesday that I'm getting this message.
2. The same code works on my development environment.

This happens after I commit any change, even for the first time, and after that there is no turning back, so I have to delete it and create it again.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks anyone for the help.

Comment: I would check the files that are not monitored by git, if you' certain there are were no changes made to the application files. I would check the /etc/apache2 files to make sure your .conf files isn't mis-configured, then try a reload. Is the 404 page a custom page or the default 404 page,m because that makes a difference. Also it would be helpful if you could supply a little more specific detail.

Comment: Well check if the file - after commit - really got into the webroot where you're requesting it when you get the 404. That would clarify if the file is actually there or not.

Comment: What do your logs say? You can check your logs by either using `rhc tail <appname>` or by ssh'ing into your application and checking in your ~/app-root/logs directory.

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you found a way why it was happening?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a shot in the dark, but do you put your php files into a subdirectory called php? If so, openshift automatically sets that directory to be your document root. It would certainly result in a 404  if you navigated to the /index.html when index.html is actually one folder up.

You can read about the way that openshift automatically sets the document root here: https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today because I was not commiting all of the files.

You should use:

```
git add -A
```

This will add all of the files in the directory to your next commit, without this command, only the files that already existed and were changed (apparently) would be commited.
After that, use:

```
git commit -a -m 'commit message'
```

Now your files should be uploaded to the server.

Also, use `git status` to see the files staged for commit and the ones that are not.